# celery show task list but won't receive task

Tags: python-3.x, flask, celery

Working on a flask application, I recently refactor it to multiple modules. Now when I distributed celery code, it stopped working

## flask_celery.py

```
from celery import Celery

def make_celery(app):
  celery = Celery(
    app.import_name,
    backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
    broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']
  )
  celery.conf.update(app.config)

  class ContextTask(celery.Task):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with app.app_context():
            return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

  celery.Task = ContextTask
  return celery
```

## app.py

```
from flask import Flask,has_request_context,request
from apis import api
from flask_celery import make_celery

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
  CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://localhost:6379',
  CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://localhost:6379'
)

api.init_app(app)

celery = make_celery(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run(debug=True)
```

## task.py

```
    from celery import current_app as celery

    @celery.task(name="this is my task")
    def shutdown():
     print('worked')
```

## api.py

```
    import task
    @snap.route('/<string:uuid>/shutdown')
    class shutdown(Resource):
     def post(self,uuid):
       task.shutdown.delay()
       return 'shutdown_initiated',202,header
```

[image]

It shows the task in task list but never receives it.

Comment: How do you run your Celery worker? - Could you please paste the whole command-line?

Comment: celery -A app.celery  worker --loglevel INFO